# Can't establish SSL connection to MongoDB from NodeJS program

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl

I am trying to connect a mongod instance from NodeJS program using Mongoose that configured with SSL connection but I'm getting the following error on the mongod console: "Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: The server is configured to only allow SSL connections."

The mongod instance is initiated as follow:

`mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile C:/Users/MyUsername/Path/mongodb.pem`

I tried to use MongoClient instead of mongoose but nothing new happened.
This is my piece of code:

```
if(envConfig.config.db.tls === true){
     let certFile = [fs.readFileSync("C:/PATH/TO/Key/mongoDB.pem")];
     mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/DB_NAME?ssl=true",{
         server:{
             sslValidate: true,
             sslCA: certFile
         }
     });
 }else{
       mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${dbUrl}`,options);
 }
```

It is not something about the PEM file because when I start the mongod as I wrote and use SSL connection with MongoDB Compass using the same PEM file from the code - it works.

MongoDB version: 3.6.0

Mongoose version: 4.13.6

Happy if someone will guide me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are you able to connect to mongo via command line or GUI like Rabo3T? Because you have specified the private key of a certificate but not the actual certificate. I assume you should specify both of them `--sslPEMKeyFile` and `--sslCAFile`

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect via Mongo Compass as I mentioned before. Also tried to use the "--sslCAFile C:/PATH/TO/CERTIFICATE.crt" and still - same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Problem was using express-session middelware and trying to connect the DB with incorrect connection string, that what caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should refer to the question [Mongoose SSL, connection not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32833298/9722636)

You should specify `{server: {ssl: true}` parameter and I think your problem will be solved

Comment: Tried it, same results

Answer (score 0):

If you initiate MongoDB daemon with private key and certificate

```
mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile C:/Users/MyUsername/Path/mongodb.pem --sslCAFile C:/Users/MyUsername/Path/mongodb.crt
```

You can connect from Node JS like

```
if(envConfig.config.db.tls === true){
 let key = fs.readFileSync("C:/Users/MyUsername/Path/mongodb.pem");
 let crt = fs.readFileSync("C:/Users/MyUsername/Path/mongodb.crt");
 mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/DB_NAME?ssl=true",{
     server:{
         "sslValidate" :true
         "sslKey": key,
         "sslCert": crt, // if you have one certificate you can use `sslCert` parameter
     }
 });
}else{
  mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${dbUrl}`,options);
}
```

More detail explanation of SSL connection via Node JS you can go [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/reference/connecting/ssl/)